# libsvm: read vectors from word2vec

Tags: ruby, libsvm, word2vec

Is there an easy way to use w2v's output vectors in libsvm?
There are two output formats for w2v: binary and text. In the text format each line begins with a word followed by a space-separated vector. e.g.:

`something -0.197045 -0.292196 -0.107292 -0.168469 0.114897 -0.006383 -0.000056 0.068514 -0.079548 0.251488 0.185607 0.248675 -0.058647 0.062771 0.129014 -0.024715 -0.168974 -0.035367 -0.009597 0.090379 0.030133 0.017338 0.062264 -0.219165 -0.214198 0.226869 -0.058710 0.034563 -0.046304 0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way with ruby:

First require the [libsvm wrapper](https://github.com/febeling/rb-libsvm):

`require 'libsvm'`

read the vectors file (assuming textual form):

`lines = File.readlines('vectors.txt')`

insert to a hash

`words = {}
lines[1..-1].each{ |l| sp = l.strip.split; words[sp[0]] = sp[1..-1].map(&:to_f) }`

and finally use libsvm:

`examples = words.values.map { |ary| Libsvm::Node.features(ary) }`